# WPS Office - index file contents

Tags: windows-search

I recently started using [WPS Office](http://wps.com) as a lightweight alternative to
Microsoft Office. However on my system it appears to not index file contents.
For example if I have a spreadsheet with the word `hello` in it, Windows Search
will not find the file as it should.

Am I missing something or is this not possible with WPS Office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the [IFilter](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/IFilter) plugin. It is included with
Microsoft Office, LibreOffice and OpenOffice.

For use with other suites, it will need to be [downloaded](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20109).

Answer (score 1):

File types not recognised by default by the **Windows Indexing Service** and **Windows Search** require an [**IFilter**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFilter) to allow for indexing and full text searches. You can see a list of all installed IFilters using [**IFilter Explorer**](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/08/16/windows-ifilter-explorer/):

[image: 1]

So unless WPS Office provides the appropriate IFilters for its own file formats or you can obtain these from elsewhere, you're out of luck.

Comment: If the file formats used by WPS Office are the same as those of MS Office, of course the [IFilters for the latter](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/DownloadsDrillInResults.aspx?q=filter+pack) will work.